# Override block in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I want to override getCustomizedOptionValue function in

**Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn**

In etc\adminhtml\di.xml:

```
 <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn" type="XXX\ProductInfo\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn" />
```

**In block:**

```
<?php

namespace XXX\ProductInfo\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column;

    class DefaultColumn extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn
    {   
        public function getCustomizedOptionValue($optionInfo)
        {
            echo "dgggggggggggggfgd";exit;

        }
    }
```

Not working ..

If anything i want to do that..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than extending block, You should use plugin for it.

your custom module di.xml as below:

```
<config>
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name">
        <plugin name="DefaultColumnPlugin" type="XXX\ProductInfo\Plugin\Items\Column\DefaultColumn" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create a file DefaultColumn.php at location XXX\ProductInfo\Plugin\Items\Column

```
<?php

namespace XXX\ProductInfo\Plugin\Items\Column;

class DefaultColumn{

}
```

As per your requirement use Before, Around and After method.

Answer (score 0):

This block also extended in another block Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name.

so need to change

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn" type="XXX\ProductInfo\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn" />
```

into

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name" type="XXX\ProductInfo\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn" />
```